# VScode LaTeX on Mac: Stuck on "activating extension"

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

LaTeX VScode on mac - stuck on activating extensions

I've reinstalled VScode and all the libraries several times but I still can't get my latex project to compile. VScode is stuck on *activating extensions*:

I'm using version:

LaTeX Workshop
v9.11.4
James Yu

I've tried a full reinstall and checked that my LaTeX distribution is working. any ideas?

I reinstalled VScode and disabled all extensions, re-enabling one by one and it still didn't fix the issue.

I also tried editing in another TeX editor and it compiled no issue.

Comment: If you are cross-posting the same question on multiple communities, you should add links to all other versions in every post!

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688376/latex-vscode-on-mac-stuck-on-activating-extensions

Comment: Great. So you’ve identified it as a cross post. What’s the solution?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyzc can you please provide a solution or kindly stop

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz